# Playing youtube video in full screen mode

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a youtube video file(.3GP) in full screen mode. My youtube url directly opens the video in fullscreen mode. Below is my code to play the video, but it never played. Every time I ran the code, it says - "Unable to Play Video. Sorry, this video cannot be played."

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);                        
    MediaController mc=new MediaController(this);
    mc.setEnabled(true);
    vv.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/Iq81rUGQofk"));
    vv.setMediaController(mc);
    vv.requestFocus();
    vv.showContextMenu();
    vv.start(); 

}
```

It is compiled successfully and when I ran the project, I am getting the below exception:

```
11-19 03:32:06.097: E/MediaPlayer(12675): Unable to to create media player
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675): Unable to open content: http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/Iq81rUGQofk
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:844)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:806)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:227)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.widget.VideoView.access$2300(VideoView.java:55)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:506)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1622)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2447)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4479)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-19 03:32:06.097: W/VideoView(12675):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is a .3GP video, any thoughts on this..

Comment: Hi, android won't support 3GP videos? Can some one please look

Comment: I assure you that Android Supports .3gp video that is the Native video format. According to your CatLog your problem is at the first 3 lines defined in the catlog. I will explain in the simplest terms "Your problem is in your data source" - try using another link or maybe something like "http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yOUbW2A-e2Q". Also if the above is all of your code you got a few errors in the way things are written. Hope that puts you in the correct direction.